# Kotlin suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body

Tags: kotlin, jvm

I'm trying to loop through a map and call a method within that map that returns a Mono.

This is the code:

```
class MyService(
    private val client: ApiClient
) {
  suspend fun search(code: String): List<MyResponse> {
  
  val request = SearchByPhraseRequest(
      phrase = code
  )
  val apiResponse = client(request).awaitFirstOrNull()?.content

  return apiResponse
  ?.stream()
  ?.map {
    if (it.firstName == null && it.surname == null) {
         val allDetails = client.getAllDetails(code).awaitFirst() ***
         // do something with above value
        }
      }
    }

    MyResponse(
      name = "${it.firstName}"
    )
    }?.toList() ?: emptyList()
  }
}
```

Method within ApiClient:

```
fun getAllDetails(code: String): Mono<AllResponse> {

    val responseType = object : ParameterizedTypeReference<AllResponse>() {}
    return webClient
      .get()
      .uri("/external-url/$code")
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(responseType)
}
```

Now the above code fails to compile around the *** above with a *Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body* message.

When I change this from `awaitFirst()` to `block()` it compiles but throws an *Unexpected error: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-5 @coroutine#2* error at runtime.

Any ideas how I can get around this?

Comment: What is `stream()` here, what is its return type? Looks a little as Java Stream API, but there is no collect, so I guess this is something different. I believe this code should work as long as you use `map()` from Kotlin stdlib or other inlined mapping function.

Comment: Ahh, ok, due to formatting I missed `toList()`. If `apiResponse` is a list or other iterable then just remove `stream()` - then I think it should work.